# Spark exception with java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.unkrig.jdisasm.Disassembler

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm running the spark version 2.1.0 and I'm getting the following exception. I'm getting the results but it's throwing the exception

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.unkrig.jdisasm.Disassembler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.codehaus.janino.SimpleCompiler.disassembleToStdout(SimpleCompiler.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.janino.SimpleCompiler.compileToClassLoader(SimpleCompiler.java:404)
    at org.codehaus.janino.ClassBodyEvaluator.compileToClass(ClassBodyEvaluator.java:311)
    at org.codehaus.janino.ClassBodyEvaluator.cook(ClassBodyEvaluator.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.janino.SimpleCompiler.cook(SimpleCompiler.java:196)
    at org.codehaus.commons.compiler.Cookable.cook(Cookable.java:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$expressions$codegen$CodeGenerator$$doCompile(CodeGenerator.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$$anon$1.load(CodeGenerator.scala:998)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$$anon$1.load(CodeGenerator.scala:995)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3599)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2379)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2342)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2257)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4000)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4004)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4874)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$.compile(CodeGenerator.scala:890)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:357)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2371)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2765)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2377)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2405)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2404)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withCallback(Dataset.scala:2778)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.count(Dataset.scala:2404)
```

I'm just reading the text file and print the count

```
val rdd = sparkLocal.read.text("/data/logs/file.log")
println(rdd.count)
```

But I'm getting the result

This is my build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies ++= {
  val akkaVersion = "2.4.10"
  val sparkVersion = "2.1.0"

  Seq(
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor"                           % akkaVersion,
    "org.apache.spark"  %%  "spark-core"                          % sparkVersion,
    "org.apache.spark"  %%  "spark-sql"                           % sparkVersion,
    "org.apache.spark"  %%  "spark-hive"                          % sparkVersion,
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j"                           % akkaVersion,
    "org.apache.spark"  %% "spark-streaming"                      % sparkVersion
  )
}
```

Anyone please help me

Comment: You are missing something somewhere. If all you were doing is that then you wouldn't be getting this error. Are you running from spark-shell? Did you build and spark-submit? What's your build.sbt look like...There is something missing here

Comment: I modified the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having the same issue, which seems to be caused by [this issue of the Janino compiler](https://github.com/janino-compiler/janino/issues/13).

The issue has been closed and according to the [change log](http://janino-compiler.github.io/janino/changelog.html) the fix should be included in version Version 3.0.7, released on 2017-03-22, which is already [on Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.janino/janino/3.0.7).

I have added an explicit

```
libraryDependencies += "org.codehaus.janino" % "janino" % "3.0.7"
```

to my `build.sbt` and so far it seems to solve the problem.

Comment: I'm using java and tried to add this version of the dependency but I keep having the same error

Answer (score -1):

val rdd = sc.textFile("/data/logs/file.log")
println(rdd.count)

for more use link

https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-reference-applications/logs_analyzer/chapter1/spark.html

Comment: I'm not using the dfatabricks driver, Anyway thanks for your answer